# "Method or data member not found" error message

Tags: excel, vba

So at the moment I have this piece of code and when I press the button that runs it the error "Method or data member not found" and it highlights the line "Question13.hide"

I have reused the same piece of code for all of my user forms and it only gives me the error on screen 13, why is this happening?

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

```
'Option 1
If CheckBox1.Value = True Then Worksheets("Results").Range("D54").Value = True
If CheckBox1.Value = True Then Worksheets("Results").Range("D54").Interior.ColorIndex = 10
If CheckBox1.Value = True Then Worksheets("Results").Range("D54").Font.Bold = True
If CheckBox1.Value = False Then Worksheets("Results").Range("D54").Value = False
If CheckBox1.Value = False Then Worksheets("Results").Range("D54").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
If CheckBox1.Value = False Then Worksheets("Results").Range("D54").Font.Bold = True

'Option 2
If CheckBox2.Value = True Then Worksheets("Results").Range("E54").Value = True
If CheckBox2.Value = True Then Worksheets("Results").Range("E54").Interior.ColorIndex = 10
If CheckBox2.Value = True Then Worksheets("Results").Range("E54").Font.Bold = True
If CheckBox2.Value = False Then Worksheets("Results").Range("E54").Value = False
If CheckBox2.Value = False Then Worksheets("Results").Range("E54").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
If CheckBox2.Value = False Then Worksheets("Results").Range("E54").Font.Bold = True

'Option 3
If CheckBox3.Value = True Then Worksheets("Results").Range("F54").Value = True
If CheckBox3.Value = True Then Worksheets("Results").Range("F54").Interior.ColorIndex = 10
If CheckBox3.Value = True Then Worksheets("Results").Range("F54").Font.Bold = True
If CheckBox3.Value = False Then Worksheets("Results").Range("F54").Value = False
If CheckBox3.Value = False Then Worksheets("Results").Range("F54").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
If CheckBox3.Value = False Then Worksheets("Results").Range("F54").Font.Bold = True

'Option 4
If CheckBox4.Value = True Then Worksheets("Results").Range("G54").Value = True
If CheckBox4.Value = True Then Worksheets("Results").Range("G54").Interior.ColorIndex = 10
If CheckBox4.Value = True Then Worksheets("Results").Range("G54").Font.Bold = True
If CheckBox4.Value = False Then Worksheets("Results").Range("G54").Value = False
If CheckBox4.Value = False Then Worksheets("Results").Range("G54").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
If CheckBox4.Value = False Then Worksheets("Results").Range("G54").Font.Bold = True

Question13.Hide
Question14.Show

End Sub
```

Comment: Which line causes the error? Your code can be made a lot more efficient, but let's fix it first. :)

Comment: It is on the "Question13.Hide" line, it only highlights the word "Hide"

Comment: Assuming that is actually the name of a Userform and not another control, do you have any code in the `Userform_Deactivate` event of that form?

Comment: Yes, it is a questionnaire and each userform is called "question1, question2, etc" and all I have is a "Unload Question13" for each userform which is only executed on the very last userform when the user submits all of the answers.

Comment: Are you sure that, when try to run the above code, the form "Question3" is visible? Please try to firstly check if `Question3.Visible = True`... You say something about "Question3" and your code contains "Question13". Could this be the problem...?

Comment: Yes, basically on the userform called question12 the line of code "Question12.Hide
Question13.Show" is shown so it can stop showing the userform with question 12 and show the one with question13

Comment: Sorry, it was an issue, I meant "Question 13" not "Question 3" on the post

Comment: If that code is in Question 13, then use `Me.Hide` instead.

Comment: Me.Hide worked but now in the userform "question17" when I do "Question18.Show" it gives me the same error of "Method or data member not found"

Comment: Perhaps you added a control called `Question18` or a variable of that name?

Comment: what do you mean by a "control" ? I do not have any variables declared so it should not be an issue

Comment: In the properties window for each form is the (name) and the caption the same ?

Comment: @CDP1802 I have changed the captions to match the name of each userform but it still gives me the same error as earlier

Comment: Do you have a form with the (name) = "Question18" ?

Comment: @CDP1802 Yes, I just fixed it but what I had to do is change the name of the form to a new one and hide/unhide that one, I dont know why it did not work with the original name

Answer (score 1):

Rather than copying the code onto each form put this into module

```
Sub UpdateSheet(ByRef frm As UserForm, ByRef rng As Range)

    Dim i As Integer, chk As Object

    For i = 1 To 4
        Set chk = frm.Controls.Item("CheckBox" & i)
        rng.Value = chk.Value
        rng.Font.Bold = True
        If chk.Value = True Then
           rng.Interior.ColorIndex = 10
        Else
           rng.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
        Set rng = rng.Offset(0, 1)
    Next

End Sub
```

and then put this code on each form changing the "D54" and Userform2 to suit each question

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    ' form Question 1
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Results").Range("D54")
    Module1.UpdateSheet Me, rng
    Me.Hide
    UserForm2.Show

End Sub
```